# HDI: Copy a file from SharePoint List to Local Disk

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have a simple tray application for copying files from one location to multiple location at a timed interval (daily job)

The System.IO.File.Copy method does not copy from a SharePoint folder.  Is there a way to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do this you have to access the folder correctly and have the web client turned on.  If your sharepoint farm is http://mysp and the doc lib you want to access is at  http://mysp/sub/sub1/mydocs then you have to put the path to the file as  \\mysp\sub\sub1\mydocs.  Also, the web client service must be turned on so that your OS can access the folder via webdav.